# Chemistry using integration

Tags: calculus

I was given this homework problem and I cant really figure out how to start or finish it.

> In Purdue's Chemistry department, the chemists have found that in a water based solution containing $12$ grams of certain undissolved chemicals, the rate of change of the amount of chemicals dissolved in the solution is proportional to the amount of the undissolved chemicals. Let $Q(t)$ (in grams) be the amount of dissolved chemicals at time $t$ and let $k$ be the positive proportionality constant. The differential equation describing the given situation is:

Can anyone show me how they would solve this problem?

Comment: You've had three questions put on hold and several others badly received this week. Please [edit] your question to include your own thoughts and efforts, keeping in mind that this is *not* a do-my-homework site.

Answer (score 3):

Start by writing out what's given.

- $Q(t)$ is the amount (in grams) of dissolved chemical
- $\frac{dQ(t)}{dt}$ is the rate of change of the amount of dissolved chemical
- $\frac{dQ(t)}{dt} \propto (12-Q(t))$ is given by the proportionality statement and the given that we start with 12 grams of undissolved chemicals.

This implies

$$\frac{dQ(t)}{dt} = k(12-Q(t)).$$

with $Q(t = 0) = 0$.

Can you now solve this?